# svg line of length "l" with distance "d" between two lines

Tags: javascript, html, math, svg

I am trying to draw vertical lines of length 60 at a distance of 180 from each other.

`depth` is an arithmetic series with `a1 = 1` and `d = 1`

---

**Attempt:**

```
`<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200">
    ${[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map( function (depth) {
        function getY1 (depth) {
            return (depth * 180) 
        }   

        function getY2 (depth) {
            return (depth * 180) + 60
        }

        return `<line x1="100" y1="${getY1(depth)}" x2="100" y2="${getY2(depth)}" stroke="black" />`
    }).join('')
}
</svg>`
```

I get lines of length 60 at distance of 120. How can I get them to be at a distance 180?
*More generally, how can I draw lines of length `l` at distance `d` from each other?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make line stroke length 60 and empty distance 180, you need to make increment    180+60=240  (in general `L+d`)

```
return (depth * 240) 
..
return (depth * 240) + 60
```

Comment: How did you determine this? What concepts of Arithmetic (or coordinate geometry) are used here? I have to make many more lines and paths like this, so it will be good if I know the right concepts to learn.

Comment: I'm ... slightly confused. If lesson lasts 45 minutes and break lasts 15 minutes, then the next lesson starts a hour after the first. It is the same concept. Period of periodic sequence is sum of all elementary parts.